# Regex for underscore delimited table names with optional underscores

Tags: regex

I need to extract the name from a number of underscore delimited table names, they always end with a 3 digit letter code and can optionally have an underscore delimited 32 character GUID. Optionally the table name itself can have underscores

e.g.

| String | Expected Output |
| --- | --- |
| TableName_d835b913bdab4fed861805f26ce6c953_abc | TableName |
| TableName_abc | TableName |
| Table_Name_abc | Table_Name |

I can use Regex

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9]+)_?([a-zA-Z0-9]{32})?(_[a-z]{3})
```

Which works for the first 2 examples but fails for the last one.

Using

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)_?([a-zA-Z0-9]{32})?(_[a-z]{3})
```

Results in the first example including the GUID in the output. I tried the lookahead options but those don't seem to work here as I want to include or exclude some of the capture group based on the following string.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple addition is to use a lazy quantifier (notice the additional `?` towards the end of the first capture group):

```regex
(^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+?)_?([a-zA-Z0-9]{32})?(_[a-z]{3})
```

By default, quantifiers are greedy (e.g. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` where the `+` is the quantifier), meaning that they'll try to match as many times as possible. In this case, both the first capture group (`(^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+?)`) and the symbol(s) after it (`_?`) are looking for underscores. However, as the first capture group has a greedy quantifier in it, it's going to keep going consuming, without consideration for leaving any for its neighbor, until it can't find a match. Meaning `_?` will never receive its underscore.

A lazy quantifier (e.g. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+?`) on the other hand, works in the opposite fashion. After the first match, it's always "giving up" the string to the next portion of the regex, effectively allowing its neighbor to try and find a match before it does. Hence why this works.

Answer (score 2):

You can optionally match the underscore and the 32 character string, and if the table name can contain double underscores and also end on an underscore use a non greedy character class allowing to match the underscore.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]+?)(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]{32})?_[a-z]{3}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O4fstU/1/)

If the table name can not have consecutive underscores, and can not end on an underscore, you can use an optional lazy repeated group starting with an underscore.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*?)(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]{32})?_[a-z]{3}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WcXeUr/1)